# How to remove javascript malware in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, security, firewall, malware

This is my site - (redacted site URL with malware from an XSS exploit - for security reasons)

I created this website in wordpress and suddenly realized malware in my site after google ads stopped and warned me.

Below are the malwares found by sucuri sitecheck.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.oclaserver.com/apu.php?zoneid=1903718"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.oclaserver.com/apu.php?zoneid=1903718"></script>
```

All my other wordpress websites got the same malware but my hard coded sites doesn't have any malwares. I want to know what is causing these malwares to come again and again even after I reinstall wordpress soo many times. And I want help in removing malwares making them not come again.

Please Help Me.

Comment: When I access your website and monitor the network to view loaded resources, I do not see the scripts you mention. Are you certain that your computer has not been infected?

Comment: First off, if your site has malware - then don't send people to it by putting the URL to the website! This is potentially dangerous to other users. Also StackOverflow is about programming related questions, this is probably better meant for: https://security.stackexchange.com/  or since it's wordpress - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No... my pc is clean. I found the malware codes in wp-includes/wp-tmp.php file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn more about Cross-Site Scripting here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Wordpress is commonly susceptible to XSS attacks in the form of comments, various plugins, lack of good security hardening practices by wordpress administrators, and even ads from Google and other ad vendors.

Your specific issue from Sucuri Site Check states:

> Malware entry: rogueads.unwanted_ads
>   Description: Varios malicious injections that result in displaying ads (or opening pop-up or pop-under windows)without site owner's consent. Such injections may utilize scripts from legitimate ad networks

You should probably attempt to figure out the source of the exploit and fix that, your best bet is security.stackexchange.com or since it's wordpress - wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll get help from "wordpress.stackexchange.com".

Comment: @cheesyblast make sure to search for potential answers that already exist. It's likely this question has been asked and resolved previously.

Comment: it was asked and answered before. But those answers say to remove wordpres and reinstall OR find the js code and remove them. I want to know how to make them not come again and again.

Comment: @cheesyblast ya, that's a process, there are security plugins that can be added, plus security hardening at the webserver level with .htaccess rules - several guides available. The problem is that, a wordpress plugin itself may get compromised from time to time.

Comment: Yes, I think the malware comes through a plugin.i have a security plugin for basic firewall protection and brutforce prot. But it isn't worth. I asked the question in stackexchange, I think I will find an answer.